# Purchasing iPhone from Canada AppStore with US credit card

Tags: iphone, apple-store

I am looking to purchase an iPhone for a friend who stays in Canada. I am making the payment with my US credit card. So, I went to the Canada Apple store(apple.com/ca) to do the purchase. However,when I attempted to fill in the credit card billing address, it looks like they accept only canada-based billing addresses. Unfortunately, my friend doesn't have a credit card, so I must be the one to pay for it.

How do I get around this? I really need to complete the purchase as soon as possible, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

Easy. Buy a Gift card in the amount of the total purchase and then email your friend the gift card

Comment: 1. apple has several gift card options - use care to get the right one. 2. Most gift cards only work in the country of purchase - use care you don't lock up $500 give or take on the wrong store. Western Union or similar might be a better plan.